# ApplicationInsights.config performance counter format

Tags: azure, configuration, performancecounter

I'm trying to setup some Azure server side performance counters.  i went into the metrics explorer in portal.azure.com and after seeing them missing and researching a bit I added the config that I'll paste below to the root ApplicationInsights.config and the one in the bin folder.  I want basic stuff like Processor CPU, Processor time, memory usage, etc but its still saying 'No data for 'x'' when I check that checbox in the chart details.  I also am having trouble mapping the counters mentioned in the chart details blade to the config syntax/ceremony that Azure wants in order to make it go (Star Trek reference).  Please help!  Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings"><InstrumentationKey>foobarkey</InstrumentationKey>
<TelemetryModules>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.RuntimeTelemetry.RemoteDependencyModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.RuntimeTelemetry"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCollector">
<Counters>
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="Processor Time" />
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Process CPU" ReportAs="Process CPU" />
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Memory\Available Bytes" ReportAs="Available Bytes" />
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\.NET CLR Exceptions(??APP_CLR_PROC??)\# of Exceps Thrown / sec" ReportAs="CLR Exceps per sec" />
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Private Bytes" ReportAs="Private Bytes" />
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\IO Data Bytes/sec" ReportAs="IO Data Bytes" />
    <Add PerformanceCounter="\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" ReportAs="Processor Time" />
</Counters>
</Add>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryModules.WebRequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryModules.WebExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryModules.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
</TelemetryModules>
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.Channel.TelemetryChannel, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.TelemetryChannel"/>
  <ContextInitializers>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.ContextInitializers.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.ContextInitializers.DeviceContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/
</ContextInitializers>
<TelemetryInitializers>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebSyntheticTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebOperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebOperationIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebUserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.WebSessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.TelemetryInitializers.DomainNameRoleInstanceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/>
</TelemetryInitializers>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things,

In 
`<Add  Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web.ContextInitializers.DeviceContextInitializer, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Web"/` you are missing the closing gt ">"

The next question is if you have added the

```
<InstrumentationKey>...</InstrumentationKey>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I really appreciate your help. We got App Insights working a while back, but I neglected to post updates on here.  I can't remember everything we did to fix it offhand, but I will try to recall it.  One sidenote: we are using New Relic as a replacement for AppInsights now and are finding it much more useful!